# python program for fetching link from a page

Tags: python, browser, selenium, urllib

I am trying to download an entire play list for Android development tutorial from Youtube. So I used [savefrom](http://en.savefrom.net/) for generating playlist for download. But the problem is that I have so many videos in that playlist.
So, I decided to write a python script for making this work simpler.
But the problem is it uses Java Script to generate the link so I cant able to fetch generated link using javascript()

Example:
http://ssyoutube.com/watch?v=AfleuRtrJoA
It takes 5 sec to generate download links.

I want to get page source only after 5 sec **from the browse**.

For this kind of work I found a good package named [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def savefromnotnet(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
    browser.get(url) # Load page
    time.sleep(5) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
    return browser.page_source()

source = savefromnotnet("http://ssyoutube.com/watch?v=AfleuRtrJoA")
```

The `savefromnotnet` function open's Firefox and it will request the url, up to this every thing works fine.
But when I want to get page source `browser.page_source()` it shows the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 523, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\BK\Desktop\Working Folder\Python Temp\temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    source = savefromnotnet("http://ssyoutube.com/watch?v=AfleuRtrJoA")
  File "C:\Users\BK\Desktop\Working Folder\Python Temp\temp.py", line 8, in savefromnotnet
    return browser.page_source()
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Comment: Add link to playlist. And show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occured on following line.

```
return browser.page_source()
```

I think brackets did not need.

```
return browser.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not !

```
pcode = wdriver.page_source()
```

is absoluteley right call. By auto-complete in python ide.

I have the same problem. Looks like we need to encode page-sourse text variable in somethind like classic ANSI